# Perl + DBD:: Oracle: upload a string containing spaces to the Oracle DB

Tags: perl

I have a CSV whihc contains 3 fields as below:

```
value1, value2, value 3
```

Note: there is a space between "value" and "3" in the 3rd field.

I am uploading this data row by row to Oracle DB using perl DBD::Oracle and DBI.

here is the query that I am using to upload:

```
$dbh->do ("INSERT INTO $table VALUES ($col1_value, $col2_value, $col3_value)");
```

however, it is faling to upload and complaining like below:

```
DBD::Oracle::db do failed: ORA-00917: missing comma (DBD ERROR: error possibly near <*> indicator at char 103 in 'INSERT INTO TABLE_NAME VALUES (value1, value2, value <*>3 )')
```

So it is failing on hte 3rd value whihc contains a space.

could you guide me on how to upload the string with "Space" in it to Oracle.

BTW, I am not oracle guy so please point me if anything that I am doing is wrong.

Thnaks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For many reasons (security, efficiency, correctness) you want to be using [placeholders](https://metacpan.org/module/DBI#Placeholders-and-Bind-Values) to put values into SQL.

```
my $rows = $dbh->do (
    "INSERT INTO $table VALUES (?, ?, ?)",
    undef,
    $col1_value, $col2_value, $col3_value
);
```

This avoids needing to do any escaping both for syntactical and security purposes.

Comment: Bull's EYE !!! Thanks Schwern for the lightening fast response . Thank you so very much.